# Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain

Tags: csom, error, ad

I wrote the following code some years ago (or maybe I took it from the web, don't remember):

```
protected static CustomUser GetSiteUser(IIdentity identity, string siteUrl)
    {
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            // resolve user principal using regular login name or e-mail:
            ClientResult<PrincipalInfo> userPrincipal = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(
              context,
              context.Web,
              identity.Name, // normal login name
              PrincipalType.User,
              PrincipalSource.All,
              context.Web.SiteUsers,
              false);

            context.ExecuteQuery(); <-- error thrown here

            // ensure that the user principal was resolved:
            if (userPrincipal.Value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // get a User instance based on the encoded login name from userPrincipal
            User user = context.Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(userPrincipal.Value.LoginName);

            context.Load(user);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            return BuildUser(user);
        }
    }
```

I use it in a web application in order to load the SharePoint user from the Identity. It worked fine for years, yesterday it started to throw the following error when loading the user:

```
System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131014)
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.InternalGetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32 hr, IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis, Boolean fForWinRT)
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32 hr, IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UnsafeNativeMethods.IADsPathname.Retrieve(Int32 lnFormatType)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.LoadDomainInfo()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.get_UserSuppliedServerName()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsMemberOfInStore(GroupPrincipal g, Principal p)
```

By restarting the application pools of the IIS it works for some hours, then it starts with the errors again.
Any idea how to understand what the problem is?

**Edit**:
Forgot to mention: SharePoint OnPremise 2016, WebApp running on .NET 4.7.2 with Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM 16.0.4690.1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days ago I installed the Juli 2022 CU KB5002231 updrading to 16.0.5266.1000 and it seems to be fixed. Last 48 hours I got no errors.